# Syntax Highlighter server-side Java library

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a multi-language syntax highlighting solution that works on the server side, **not** on client side. It should support at least XML, HTML, Java and PHP source code highlighting, and be preferably open-source and written in Java. It should output HTML of the highlighted text + optionally CSS to support it.

Something like this must already exist? But I can't seem to be able to find it..

Note: I do *NOT* need a javascript solution like the google's prettify.js. I know there are plenty of these around. I need a server-side solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [rsyntaxtextarea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/).

There is also [jhighlight](http://java.net/projects/jhighlight/), but their page gives a 404. See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uwyn/jhighlight) for some details about jhightlight

Comment: Thanks, but [rsyntaxtextarea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/) is a Swing app and [jhighlight](http://freecode.com/projects/jhighlight) doesn't support PHP syntax...